# how to show check mark when any cell value is selected

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have the answers showns in table view i want that if users selet any of the cell is should get checkmarked image with text side and if mean time he selects another cell from first cell checkmark should be removed and shown on the selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .h file create variable

```
UItableviewCell *selectedCell;
```

In didSelectRow method remove selection from saved cell and save new cell as selected:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    if (selectedCell) {
        selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    UItableviewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    selectedCell = cell;
}
```

To prevent problems with reusable cells u can create NSIndexPath variable instead of UITableViewCell in .h file:

```
NSIndexPath *selectedCellIndexPath;
```

and change didSelectRow method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath];
    selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    UItableviewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

Comment: but that check mark to be shown when cell is selected otherwise or not

Comment: again same issue i want that when table view is loaded all the cell don not show any thing with text when user select any cell then it show checkmark

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not a good idea. You can't count on the cells to tell u if selected or not, cells get reused and always change there state. This will cause u a lot of problems if u reuse cells, and u should...

Answer (score 2):

First add a property to your viewController .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *theSelectedIndexPath;
```

and in your .m file synthesize

```
@synthesize theSelectedIndexPath = _theSelectedIndexPath;
```

Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do

```
if (indexPath.row == self.theSelectedIndexPath.row) {
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else { 
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Don't forget to update the `theSelectedIndexPath` in   `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.theSelectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

Comment: @Eval how to save the selected row indexPath

Comment: May i suggest you change it to `self.tableView` instead of just `self`,  because i don't think everyone uses a `UITableViewController` class everytime.

Comment: i have done like this but it says property selectedIndex not found

Comment: @user1520252, try with `self.yourTableView`, this was the issue i was mentioning.

Comment: @iNoob I didn't call my table view anywhere in the code.. what do u mean??

Comment: again same dear issue not solving

Comment: @Eyal, i mean this line `if (indexPath.row == self.selectedIndexPath.row)` instead of `self.selectedIndexPath.row` i suggested you to change it to `self.tableView.selectedIndexPath.row`, because `self.selectedIndexPath` will work if the class is of type `UITableViewController`and not for `UIViewController`.

Comment: hoo I didn't mean that this is the tableView's selectedIndexPath, this is a property of the viewController, I changed the name

Answer (score 0):

1. declare a global int `selectedRow`
2. in your `tableviewDidSelectRow` set that int to the selected row.
3. also there in `tableviewDidSelectRow` make `[tableView reloadData];`
4. in your `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath` do the following:

   ```
   if (indexPath.row == selectedRow)
       cell.accessoryView = checkMark;
   else
       cell.accessoryView = nil;
   ```

where "checkMark" is an outlet to your checkmark imageview (I use custom checkmarks)

Tada!